# How can I export data from cosmosdb to .json file

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

how can I export data from cosmosdb in json file, in safe way, without locking table?
and preferred to have ability to download only some properties from document with query.

Comment: I believe that cosmosDb does not have the `lock` mechanism.

Comment: I do you want to do it with an .net app or with azure functions or other?

Comment: probably I'm mostly considering some tool, like data migration tool (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/)

Comment: Export data to where?

Comment: to json format file

Comment: CosmosDB functionality drastically differs based on the API used. Which API are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store locally or in Azure Blob storage, data migration tool can do this.

If you want to store in other service, Azure Data Factory is a choice.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file).

Answer (score -1):

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip167.html
Please try this link this contains standard migration tool and simple steps to migrate data from azure cosmos